# What is the difference between Build Active Architecture Only -> No and creating a fat binary by using lipo?

Tags: ios, xcode, lipo

Let's imagine that we're creating a static library in Xcode and in the Build Settings we set `Build Active Architecture Only` to No. Why does it still produce a library suitable only for the device currently selected (a simulator or real device)? What do we still need to create a fat binary running a script which would use `lipo` tool? Why at is the actual difference between these two? What does `lipo` do that building for all architectures doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

When you are `Building` you are using only one architecture to `Debug` on, to do a fat library your action of choice must be `Archive` that also strip all debug info from the final library.

As for why after setting `NO` it still builds only for currently selected device, check if the `Configuration` your are editing is `Debug` or `Distribution/Release`.